# ASP.Net Core spa pre-rendering with angular universal works locally but not on server

Tags: asp.net-core, angular7, angular-universal

I'm trying to set up angular universal on angular7 with asp.net core 2.1. The prerendering works perfectly on a local build but does not add code to the page source on a server in production with no errors or logs.

Due to the lack of logs I suspect this is because the server module is not loaded/ started but I have no idea why. Is this something that should be added into the web config?

I am using a windows shared plesk server which supports node.js and IIS Node. Here is a snippet from my Startup.cs

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 1000);
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
    {
        options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/main.js";
        options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment() ? new 
        AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr") : null;
        options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };
    });

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the .NET core hosting bundle installed on the production machine? https://www.microsoft.com/net/permalink/dotnetcore-current-windows-runtime-bundle-installer

Comment: Yes. To add some more info, I had this line in the Configure method of Startup.cs `app.UseSpaStaticFiles()` and I have found if I comment out this line then the pre-rending works for adding components into the app-route in index.html, but also tries to put all other files in there too. Is there a way to Exclude specific file extensions?

Comment: I believe this might have to do something with how you build your application locally and for production. I assume it goes through some CI/CD pipeline and locally is built by npm run build --prod. Check your configs, if you can, remote into the production server and check where the files are and compare it to your local environment.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After closer inspection with fiddler, it is actually returning a 400 error in the index.html for all missing files. So without `app.UseSpaStaticFiles()`  the static files cannot be found, but with `app.UseSpaStaticFiles()` it gets all the files but does not pre-render the pages

Answer (score 1):

I eventually realised I had the line `app.UseStaticFiles();` as well as `app.UseSpaStaticFiles` in Startup.cs. Removing `app.UseStaticFiles();` solved this issue. However, I am still not sure why this wasn't causing issues on a local build.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are misusing the prerendering middleware.

About prerendering: Represents the ability to build a Single Page Application (SPA) on demand so that it can be prerendered. This is only intended to be used at development time. In production, a SPA should already have been built during publishing.

You should hide that piece of code behind:

```
env.IsDevelopment()
```

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.spaservices.prerendering?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I believe you are talking about ISpaPrerendererBuilder. I am using ISpaPrerenderer to server side render dynamic content that cannot have been built during publishing